# Why is (log y) = m(log x) + c a straight line? (TMUA question)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

In the TMUA (Test of Mathematics for University Admission) specimen paper 1 there is the following question:
[image]

The solution provided is as follows:
[image]
I am having trouble understanding the opening statement - why is (log y) = m(log x) + c a straight line? When you input the equation into desmos and play around with the m, it is clearly not a straight line. Am I missing something or misunderstanding the question? Or is this solution wrong?

Comment: You're no doubt plotting $y$ against $x$ in _Desmos_, but the question is very clearly about plotting $\log y$ against $\log x$.

Comment: what you are missing is "A graph of $\log y$ against $\log x$ is drawn"

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the item is plotting $\log (y)$ to the $\log (x)$. This means that the Desmos plot ($y$ against $x$) will not be a straight line.